# How to create clusters/groups from knowing associations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, algorithm, cluster-analysis

I have a dataframe that has 2 columns: [ID, ASSOCIATED_ID]
For each ID, I have a list of other associated IDS from the dataframe.
Here is a synthesized version of it:

```
ID            ASSOCIATED_ID
1             [2,3]
2             [1,4]
3             [1]
4             [2]
5             []
```

If I want to create clusters (groups) of IDs that are associated to each other (not necessary that they have a direct association but even if there is any transitive association). How can I do that programmatically?

Comment: This is far too broad. Have you done anything to try to solve this? Stack Overflow is meant for specific technical problems. See: [ask], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/11301900.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC,you can use networkx and connect_components:

```
df_e = df.explode('ASSOCIATED_ID')

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df_e, 'ID','ASSOCIATED_ID')

[i for i in nx.connected_components(G)]
```

Output:

```
[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {nan, 5}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This helps a lot. Also is there any way with which I can get clusters where all elements of the clusters are directly related to each other. Something like a fully connected cluster. I know this might increase number of clusters and also some elements may be present in multiple clusters right?

Comment: Yes, you can return the actual subgraph of the connect components using connected_component_subgraph.

Comment: I tried using connected_component_subgraph but it returns a generator object and not the clusters itself. I want the kind of output that:
```
[i for i in nx.connected_components(G)]
```
returns to me. Just the difference would be that connected_components returns clusters where all elements are either directly or indirectly associated to each other, whereas what I need is to get clusters where every element is strictly directly associated to each other.

Comment: @aashayshah What for would like to see the cluster? A tuple?  Can you edit the question to add your expected output?

Comment: Or... better yet, start a new question and reference this one.

Comment: I would expect the output to be a dataframe that looks something like this:
```
CLUSTERS
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1,5,6]
[2,8,9,10]
[11,12,13]
```
Basically the dataframe should have only one column named CLUSTERS where each row represents a list of nodes belonging to the cluster and each of those nodes are fully connected to each other. There has to be a direct relationship between all nodes present in one cluster. This may result in one node being present in multiple clusters but that's fine. And also thanks - Scott Boston!